# Chopping items makes them Kitniyoth?

Tags: minhag, passover, mistakes, kitniyos-semigrain-legume, publications

[This article](http://www.thejewishweek.com/special_sections/special_holiday_issues/digging_your_roots) has a line in a recipe that suggests that chopping an ingredient will make it Kitniyoth.  The entire recipe is below with the line in question highlighted:

> JICAMA APPLE SLAW
>
> From Shaya Klechevsky
>
> ½ medium Jicama, peeled
> and julienned (slaw)
> 2 Granny smith apples (green),
> julienned
> 1 small red cabbage, cut into
> thin strips (slaw)
> 2 large carrots, peeled and julienned
> 1 medium red onion,
> thinly sliced half-moon
> ½ bunch fresh parsley, finely chopped
> ¼ cup dried apricots, chopped
> ¼ cup walnuts, toasted,
> **chopped (for those who eat kitniyot)**
> 1 lemon, juiced
> ½ tsp Cayenne pepper
> ¼ cup extra virgin olive oil
> kosher salt
> black pepper
> Combine the jicama, apples, cabbage, carrots, red onion and parsley and toss thoroughly to get an even mixture.
> In a small bowl, combine the lemon juice, cayenne pepper, and olive oil and whisk. Adjust seasoning (salt and pepper). Set aside when ready to use.
> Toast the walnuts in a skillet over medium-high heat until they begin to release their oil and the nutty aroma is released. Immediately transfer to a plate and allow to cool (about 10 minutes).
> When ready to serve, add the chopped toasted walnuts and chopped dried apricots to the slaw and toss. Whisk the dressing and pour over the slaw and toss to evenly coat all the ingredients.

Is this a typo or editing mistake?  Is there some reason this could be the case?

Comment: It likely is referring to the walnuts themselves, not the fact that they are chopped. But it's still strange, as walnuts are not *kitniyot* (as far as I know).

Comment: @jake, It's weird, right?

Comment: Maybe he's confusing walnuts with peanuts, which some people are machmir not to eat.

Comment: @jake I bet you're right but it's strange it slipped through the editors.  A well-placed email to the Week might clear things up

Comment: @jake, as of the publication of this article, some people are machmir not to eat [chopped] walnuts. It won't be long before you can't find Pesach products with walnuts in them, so as not to lose this segment of the market. Pecans better watch their backs.

Comment: my money is on a missing ingredient. There is nothing unaccounted for in the recipe but the recipe also does not say that chopping walnuts is optional. So my guess is that there is a missing kitniyot ingredient that was incompletely excised. This site http://feeds2.feedburner.com/atyourpalateblog doesn't have the reference

Comment: @IsaacMoses, Not to worry. It's only chopped *toasted* walnuts which are deemed *kitniyot* by this recipe. But I wouldn't be surprised if walnuts are excluded from all manufactured products just in case you should decide to apply heat to and/or apply a chopping or chopping-like procedure upon the product.

Comment: Looks to me like they just didn't realize walnuts are **not** kitniot.

Comment: Walnuts are not kitniot, but once they're chopped, it is hard to distinguish them from anything else which my be kitniot. Presumably that's why the proviso was added, in case someone bought chopped walnuts without realizing that they needed a hechsher.

Comment: @Epicentre, sounds like a basis for an answer if you have a source that this is a common policy decision in Kosher publications and/or it appears in many published recipes (preferably at least one which states this outright).

Comment: @SethJ I don't have a source, but I seem to remember having come across the idea somewhere since there is a suspicion that, without supervision, forbidden items could have got in, accidentally or deliberately. Not only that but http://www.yisi.org/yom_tov_schedule/Items%20Kosher%20for%20Pass%205770.pdf suggests that they do not need supervision (but pecans do). This is counterintuitive since the same grinder _could_ have been used for peanuts (or even actual chametz) previously and not fully cleaned - just as with many other products. If anyone can find a source either way it would be a help.

Comment: @Epicentre, just commenting on your example of peanuts, nothing else: I would hope that there is no movement to ban chopped products (for Kitniyoth reasons) out of a fear that residual chopped crumbs of peanuts, of all things, might make their way into the bag.

Comment: @SethJ - Don't worry. I'm sure someone will be so machmir that they will try.:-)

Answer (score 4):

If I recall correctly there were some concerns (at least a few years ago) with corn-derived preservatives or packaging materials with regards to some packaged nuts. It may not be "chopping the walnuts makes them kitniyot", but "your average bag of chopped walnuts bought at the store may have been treated with some kitniyot product."

But there are a zillion different customs out there of things people don't eat on Passover...

Comment: Interesting. A(ny) source here would help. +1.

Comment: From the OU-

"Raw nuts in their shell do not require Passover certification. Shelled nuts that list BHA or BHT (preservatives) in the ingredients require special Passover certification. They are sprayed on the nuts using corn derivatives (kitniyot)."


http://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/nuts/

Comment: @Yirmeyahu, btw, if you write your own answer, I'll delete mine so you can claim rep. I just wrote it so that other users wouldn't miss it if you were to delete your comment or if they skipped the comments sections of answers.

Answer (score 3):

To support for [Shalom's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29811/899) that the issue isn't about chopped nuts being kitniyot per se, but rather kitniyot being used during the processing, we see from the OU-

"Raw nuts in their shell do not require Passover certification. Shelled nuts that list BHA or BHT (preservatives) in the ingredients require special Passover certification. They are sprayed on the nuts using corn derivatives (kitniyot)."

http://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/nuts/

Answer (score 0):

Chopping items cannot make them Kitniot otherwise the Poskim would mention it. After all, at what size is it *chopped*? halves? quarters? eighths? How would one make Charoset; only with chunks of apples?

But since **[jicama is a legume](http://www.answers.com/topic/jicama)**, it probably would have been classified as Kitniot, had our European ancestors heard of them. (Along with potatoes.)

Comment: My family doesn't use nuts in charoset. We're allergic.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, it's a TUBER not a legume.